# Django model query "matching query does not exist"

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a "matching query does not exist" on my django app and I'm stumped on where the issue is. I know that means that it can't find a match to my query, but as shown below I can manually run the query via sql on the table. I'm not sure where else to look. (I've only provided a snippet of my view.py and model.py files as the other functions in them aren't relevant).

I'm running to queries and it fails on the first one. First query is `results = RateskioskEmp.objects.get(BadgeBarcodeID=barcodeid)` and the second query is `context['result_obj'] = RateskioskMain.objects.get(EID=empid)`

If I provide a manual "empid" and skip the first RateskioskEmp query it works just fine and I get results from my RateskioskMain query.

Error:

```
Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /kiosk
Exception Value: RateskioskEmp matching query does not exist.
```

Views:

```
from ratekiosk.models import RateskioskMain
from ratekiosk.models import RateskioskEmp #this is the problem model

def get_emp_by_barcode_db(barcodeid):
    results = RateskioskEmp.objects.get(BadgeBarcodeID=barcodeid)
    empid = results.EID
    return empid

def kiosk_view(request):
    context = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        barcodeid = request.POST.get('barcodeid')
        empid = get_emp_by_barcode_db(barcodeid)
        try:
            context['result_obj'] = RateskioskMain.objects.get(EID=empid)
        except Exception:
            context['result_obj'] = None
    return render(request, 'ratekiosk/kiosk.html', context)
```

Model:

```
class RateskioskEmp(models.Model):
    EID = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, default=0,)
    UserID = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=0)
    EmployeeName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=0)
    BadgeBarcodeID = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=0)
    DepartmentID = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=0)
```

Manual SQL query:

```
mysql> select eid from ratekiosk_rateskioskemp where badgebarcodeID='123456789'; 
+-----------+
| eid       |
+-----------+
| 987654321 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Anyone have any idea on what I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: Seems my form isn't returning the value from the form to the view. It was at one point, but now I get none.

Template:

```
<div class="row vertical-center-row">
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="barcodeid">Scan Your Badge</label>
                <input type="text" id="barcodeid" name="barcodeid" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
    </div></div>
```

So that's a new problem to this question.

Comment: You here filtered on `EID`, not on `BadgeBarcodeId`.

Comment: I'm providing the badgebarcodeID (I used the variable barcodeID) and I need the eid (variable used is empid)

Comment: It seems that the data arriving at your view is not what you're expecting. Did you check that after `barcodeid = request.POST.get('barcodeid')`  `barcodeid` contains what you think it contains?

Comment: There is a common error when working with forms, did you name your controls in your template?  If not, you may be receiving `None`.

Comment: Can you explain? Not sure what you mean?